# Reading and writing Windows "tags" with Python 3

Tags: windows, winapi, com, pywin32, win32com

In Windows image files can be tagged. These tags can be viewed and edited by right clicking on a file, clicking over to the Details tab, then clicking on the Tags property value cell.

I want to be able to read and write these tags using Python 3.

This is not EXIF data so EXIF solutions won't work. I believe it's part of the Windows Property System, but I can't find a reference in Dev Center. I looked into win32com.propsys and couldn't see anything in there either.

I wrote a program that does this once before, but I've since lost it, so I know it's possible. Previously I did it without pywin32, but any solution would be great. I think I used windll, but I can't remember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some sample code that's using the [IPropertyStore interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nn-propsys-ipropertystore) through `propsys`:

```
import pythoncom
from win32com.propsys import propsys
from win32com.shell import shellcon

# get PROPERTYKEY for "System.Keywords"
pk = propsys.PSGetPropertyKeyFromName("System.Keywords")

# get property store for a given shell item (here a file)
ps = propsys.SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName("c:\\path\\myfile.jpg", None, shellcon.GPS_READWRITE, propsys.IID_IPropertyStore)

# read & print existing (or not) property value, System.Keywords type is an array of string
keywords = ps.GetValue(pk).GetValue()
print(keywords)

# build an array of string type PROPVARIANT
newValue = propsys.PROPVARIANTType(["hello", "world"], pythoncom.VT_VECTOR | pythoncom.VT_BSTR)

# write property
ps.SetValue(pk, newValue)
ps.Commit()
```

This code is pretty generic for any Windows property.

I'm using [System.Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-keywords) because that's what corresponds to jpeg's "tags" property that you see in the property sheet.

And the code works for jpeg and other formats for *reading* (`GetValue`) properties, but not all Windows codecs support property *writing* (`SetValue`), to it doesn't work for writing extended properties back to a .png for example.

Comment: System.Keywords?! I'm facepalming on this one! Thank you so much for the help, this works perfectly and your code is lovely and clean. I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: Thank you, @SimonMourier. The next problem I find is that how to use relative path instead of absolute one in propsys.SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName function. I tried ".\\path\\myfile.jpg" and it raised parameter error.

Comment: @bayes - There's no way do do that with SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName ask another question.

Comment: I'm getting the error 'Import "win32com.propsys" could not be resolved'. I installed the pywin32 and still not working