# renaming video files based on EXIF data

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, rename, exif

I'm trying to rename video files based on exif data from the video file itself. I know how to get the exif data and I know how to rename files but I dont' manage to put the two together. For some reason it always hangs when it reaches the last file in the folder. I have tried a lot of things alread but none of them worked. Any help or suggestions would therefore be highly appreciated.

Here's my code (run locally in a jupyter notebook on windows 10):

```
folder = "E:\\Video\\2019"

import os.path, time
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from win32com.propsys import propsys, pscon

ref_date = datetime.date(2019, 4, 15)

for path, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        if('mp4' in filename.lower()):
            fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)  
            properties = propsys.SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(fullpath)
            dt = properties.GetValue(pscon.PKEY_Media_DateEncoded).GetValue()
            dt_creation = dt.date()
            days = (dt_creation - ref_date).days
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, str(days) + " - " + filename))
```

Comment: Add `print(filename)` before renaming to get a clue what's going wrong.

Comment: I already tried that. It finds the correct files and also calculates the days variable correctly. But then it gets stuck on the os.rename line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a problem regarding file locking and/or access rights. I noticed the same problem (got stuck on os.rename, too).
As a work-around, I used the `GPS_NO_OPLOCK`-flag, but I don't know if that has any side-effects - test and use with care.

This worked for me (Win10v2004, python-3.6.5, pywin32-300), see inline comments:

```
import os.path, time
#from datetime import datetime  # error in line: ref_date = ...
import datetime  # this works for me
import pytz
from win32com.propsys import propsys, pscon

GPS_NO_OPLOCK = 0x00000080  # not defined in propsys
# see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/ne-propsys-getpropertystoreflags
# see https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums.GETPROPERTYSTOREFLAGS
# see http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/propsys__SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName_meth.html

folder = "E:\\Video\\2019"

ref_date = datetime.date(2019, 4, 15)

for path, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        if ('.mp4' in filename.lower()):  # include '.' toavoid 'mp4' in filename
            fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            print(f'filename {filename}  fullpath {fullpath}')

            # see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61713787/reading-and-writing-windows-tags-with-python-3
            properties = propsys.SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(fullpath, None, GPS_NO_OPLOCK, propsys.IID_IPropertyStore)

            dt = properties.GetValue(pscon.PKEY_Media_DateEncoded).GetValue()
            dt_creation = dt.date()
            days = (dt_creation - ref_date).days

            #os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, str(days) + " - " + filename))
            new_name = "".join([str(days), ' - ', filename])  # be a bit more pythonic
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, new_name))
```

References:

stackoverflow: [Reading and writing Windows “tags” with Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61713787/reading-and-writing-windows-tags-with-python-3)

PyWin32 docs: [propsys.SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/propsys__SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName_meth.html)

MS docs: [GETPROPERTYSTOREFLAGS enumeration (propsys.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/ne-propsys-getpropertystoreflags)

pinvoke.net: [GETPROPERTYSTOREFLAGS (Enums)](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums.GETPROPERTYSTOREFLAGS)

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It was exactly what I was looking for :-) So far it has worked like a charm but I'll make sure to keep an eye out for any side effects.

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to upvote my answer ;)