# Adding props (tags/ keywords) to a folder using only ctypes in Python 3

Tags: windows, winapi, com, ctypes, pywin32

I'm trying to add tag to a folder using Windows API, and I've stumbled upon [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/stg/the-summary-information-property-set).

According in this article,

> to create an ANSI simple property set, you would call IPropertySetStorage::Create to create the property set, specifying PROPSETFLAG_ANSI (simple is the default type of property set), then write to it with a call to IPropertyStorage::WriteMultiple. To read the property set, you would call IPropertyStorage::ReadMultiple.

I tried doing it as the code below but get stuck because I can't find where the `IPropertySetStorage` and `IPropertyStorage` is.

```
from ctypes import sizeof

STGM_READWRITE = 0x00000002

def addTag(folder):
    shell32 = ctypes.windll.shell32

    _clsid = None # should to be the CLSID from the SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS

    # ↓↓↓↓↓↓ I can't find where should I get IPropertySetStorage
    shell32.IPropertySetStorage.Create("{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}", _clsid, 0, STGM_READWRITE)

    rglpwstrName = ["TestTag"]
    rgpropid = ["prop5"]
    cpropid = sizeof(rgpropid)

    # ↓↓↓↓↓↓ I can't find where should I get IPropertyStorage
    shell32.IPropertyStorage.WritePropertyNames(cpropid, rgpropid, rglpwstrName)

addTag(r"C:\Users\Agustin\Desktop\New folder")
```

I tried searching for answers here and in the Microsoft documentation but [(Reading and writing Windows "tags" with Python 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61713787/reading-and-writing-windows-tags-with-python-3) is the closest example I've seen. The example there is using `pywin32` but ***I want to find out if this can be pulled off using only `ctypes`***.

**My Question:** Where can I find the `IPropertySetStorage` and `IPropertyStorage`? And how can I add tag to a folder using only the Windows API with **ctypes**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hope these two documents are helpful to you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oi29500/dd236d15-5c66-4553-b1bb-cdbf1680bf1b say The following GUIDs (include this {F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9})  shall not be used in a custom property.  [Predefined Property Set Format Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/stg/predefined-property-set-format-identifiers)

Comment: Hi, is there any progress on this issue recently?