# How to edit windows file details?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, windows-explorer

In **windows explorer**, there is a long list of details you can choose to view:

[image: right click in columns and select More...]

How can I programaticaly edit theses itens in the files with **Python** or **PowerShell**?

Ex. I want all my files have "Anniversary" value equal to something. How can I edit it?

Comment: The underlying Windows API to set a property is the `IPropertyStore` interface. I couldn't find an easy-to-use PowerShell wrapper, but here is one for Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61714895/7571258

Comment: it is possible to change certain attributes like the name and the type (extension). But is it not possible to change attributes like the `file size` without physically editing the file !!